# probability - picking up from a box

Tags: probability

I have the following question, but I fail to get the right answer. There are two boxes - box $A$ and box $B$. Box $A$ has $5$ red balls and $3$ blue ones. Box $B$ has $6$ red balls and $2$ blue ones. If one randomly chooses one of the boxes and picks up $3$ balls randomly without returning them, I wish to find the probability of the third one being red considering the first two were blue. What I did was:
$$P=P\left(\left(\text{third red}\mid\text{first two blue}\right)\mid\text{box A}\right)P\left(\text{box A}\right)+P\left(\left(\text{third red}\mid\text{first two blue}\right)\mid\text{box B}\right)P\left(\text{box B}\right)=\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{11}{12}$$
But the answer seems to be $\frac{7}{8}$. What have I done wrong? I fail to see my mistake (it could be that the answers sheet contains a mistake I guess, but I tend to think I did one).

Comment: Say you are taking out $4$ balls instead of $3$ and given first $3$ are blue, you need to find probability of 4th being red. Will you still say $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, where $P(B)$ is the probability that it is box $B$? Do you see how probability of which box you have picked changes based on color of each ball you take out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attack the problem in stages.

First, you have to calculate $f(a), f(b)$ where

$f(a) =$ probability that balls are being drawn from box A and

$f(b) =$ probability that balls are being drawn from box B.

Naturally, this will involve [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), and you should expect $f(a) + f(b) = 1.$

Once you do that, you then have to calculate

$g(a) =$ chance that next ball is red, given that balls are being taken from box A and

$g(b) =$ chance that next ball is red, given that balls are being taken from box B

Then, the final computation will be

$$\left[f(a) \times g(a)\right] + \left[f(b) \times g(b)\right].$$

---

$f(a) = \frac{R}{S}$

where $R = \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{7}\right]$

and $S = \left\{\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{3}{8} \times \frac{2}{7}\right]\right\} + \left\{\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{2}{8} \times \frac{1}{7}\right]\right\}.$

This works out to $f(a) = (3/4), f(b) = (1/4).$

Then, you also have that $g(a) = (5/6)$ and $g(b) = 1$.

The numbers immediately above are explained by reasoning that if the balls are being drawn from box A, there are 6 balls left, 5 of which are red.  If the balls are being drawn from box B, then there are 6 balls left, all of which are red.

Thus, the final computation is

$$\left[(3/4) \times (5/6)\right] + \left[(1/4) \times (1)\right] = (21/24) = (7/8).$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand why wouldn't $f(a)=f(b)=1/2$. A box is chosen randomly, why should it be otherwise (I therefore don't understand the $R$ and $S$ in your calculation).

Comment: @Darkenin It is true, that given no other information, you would have that $f(a) = f(b) = (1/2).$  However, you have been given that the first two balls drawn are blue.  My calculation of $R$ represented the chance of picking box A, and then having the first two balls drawn as blue.  My calculation of $S$ has two terms, the first of which is identical to the numerator, and the second of which is the corresponding chance of selecting box B, and then drawing two consecutive blue balls. ...see next comment

Comment: @Darkenin Think about it intuitively: since box A has more blue balls than box B, it is more likely than not that the two blue balls came from Box A.  The math does in fact lead to $f(a) = (3/4).$  For a more complete understanding, you have to research Bayes Theorem.  The article that I cited in my answer is the place to start.